# Scrolling TreeViewer Tree SWT

Tags: java, tree, swt, treeviewer

My dialog have two `TreeViewer` components. The vertical scroll bars have to be synchronized. 
I have tried with `setSelection` and `setTopItem` methods but both have no effect to other tree.

```
xViewerLeft = createXViewer(leftComposite, this);
xViewerRight = createXViewer(rightComposite, this);

xViewerLeft.getTree().getVerticalBar().addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
    @Override public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
    //xViewerRight.getTree().setSelection(xViewerLeft.getTree().getSelection());
    //xViewerRight.getTree().setTopItem(xViewerLeft.getTree().getTopItem());
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are `xViewerLeft` and `xViewerRight`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution:

```
vBar1.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        @Override public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
        double y = vBar1.getSelection()*xViewerRight.getTree().view.bounds().height/100;
        NSPoint nsPoint = new NSPoint();
        nsPoint.x = 0;
        nsPoint.y = y;
        xViewerRight.getTree().view.scrollPoint(nsPoint);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Imray it is MAC OS specific class, i asume one can use Point instead

Comment: THanks. I was under the impression that SWT works across all systems. Can you tell me as well What are `xViewerLeft` and `xViewerRight`?

Comment: @Imray xViewerLeft is component from nebula package http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/xviewer/xviewer.php