# SWT: How to use only one scrollbar to scroll two seaparate viewers

Tags: java, swt, scrollbar, jface, treeviewer

I'm putting two `TreeViewers` in an SWT `Shell`.

They each have their own scrollbars. However, I would like to have only one `Scrollbar` in the `Shell` which controls the scrolling of both `TreeViewers` simultaneously.

The only example of this I've been able to find is in the Source Compare View. However, I cannot see how they did this - I have been trying to figure it out for a while. But at least I know it's possible.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

My final interface should have two `TreeViewers` and one `Scrollbar` at the left to control them both.

Comment: Do you mean that they both have a scrollbar, but moving one would move the other or do you want a single scrollbar somewhere that moves both composites?

Comment: They both have their own Scrollbar moving each of them independently. I would like to have one Scrollbar that moves both at the same time (both Trees are always the same size). (P.S. Glad to have you onboard @Baz :)

Comment: So you want 3 in total?

Comment: No, I'd like to have only one. One Scrollbar to rule them all.

Comment: If you eventually find a solution, please post it here.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you out. When i used `SWT.NO_SCROLL` for the `Tree` it stopping scrolling but `Table`, it hides vertical scroll bar and Table was scrolled when top index is set.

**Tree**

use `setTopItem(TreeItem)`-read documentation( as treeitem has child items )

**Table**

use `setTopIndex(int index)`

**example:**

```
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,false));
final Tree tree1 = new Tree(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI /*| SWT.NO_SCROLL*/);

for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
  TreeItem item = new TreeItem(tree1, SWT.NONE);
  item.setText("Tree 1 Item" + i);
}
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false);
data.heightHint=200;
tree1.setLayoutData(data);



final Tree tree2 = new Tree(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI);
tree2.setSize(200, 200);
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
  TreeItem item = new TreeItem(tree2, SWT.NONE);
  item.setText("Tree 2 Item" + i);
}
tree2.getVerticalBar().addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

  @Override
  public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    TreeItem item = tree2.getTopItem();
    int i = tree2.indexOf(item);
     item = tree1.getItem(i);
    tree1.setTopItem(item); 
  }

  @Override
  public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
  }
});
data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false);
data.heightHint=200;
tree2.setLayoutData(data);

shell.pack();
shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
  if (!display.readAndDispatch())
    display.sleep();
}
display.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that should *help* you, it's not a solution though.

I couldn't figure out how to add an additional scrollbar that imitates the others. What I did achieve, is to interlink the scrollbar movements of the two `ScolledComposites`. Maybe this helps you a little in your endeavour...

```
private static ScrolledComposite[] comps = new ScrolledComposite[2];

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    createComposite(0, shell);
    createComposite(1, shell);

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(300, shell.getSize().y);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void createComposite(final int position, Shell parent)
{
     ScrolledComposite scrolled = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);

    Composite content = new Composite(scrolled, SWT.BORDER);
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button(content, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setText("Button " + i);
    }

    scrolled.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolled.setExpandVertical(true);
    scrolled.setMinSize(content.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
    scrolled.setContent(content);

    scrolled.getHorizontalBar().addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            if(e.detail == SWT.DRAG)
            {
                ScrolledComposite source = comps[position];
                ScrolledComposite target = comps[(position + 1) % comps.length];
                int value = source.getHorizontalBar().getSelection();
                target.setOrigin(value, target.getOrigin().y);
            }
        }
    });

    comps[position] = scrolled;
}
```

Comment: The problem is I can't add TreeViewers to a ScrolledComposite

Comment: @Imray Why not? Mhm, can't you apply the same idea to `TreeViewer`s?

Comment: @Imray [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964914/vertical-align-2-jface-treeviewers-to-specific-element) might be helpful.

Comment: @Imray [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347737/scrolling-treeviewer-tree-swt) as well.